# Ellipse - Weyl's law - Mathematica

Tags: geometry

I don't have experience with Mathematica. I'd need that someone could help me. Could anyone be able to reproduce the following image by this software? Here, the blue quarter ellipse is completely outside the bold region, while the red one is inside.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[{
    x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. {x -> 5, y -> 2},
    x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. {x -> 4, y -> 3},
    a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}][[1]]

(*  {a -> Sqrt[161/5], b -> Sqrt[161]/3}  *)

x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. sol

(*  (5*x^2)/161 + (9*y^2)/161 == 1  *)

Graphics[{
  Gray,
  Opacity[.25],
  Rectangle[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 4],
  Rectangle[{#, 1}] & /@ Range[0, 4],
  Rectangle[{#, 2}] & /@ Range[0, 3],
  Opacity[1], Thick,
  Red,
  Tooltip[
   Circle[{0, 0}, {5, 3}, {0, Pi/2}],
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. {a -> 5, b -> 3}],
  Blue,
  Tooltip[
   Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b} /. sol, {0, Pi/2}],
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. sol]}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 7], Range[0, 5]},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"})]
```

[image]

Comment: The bold part is too light. Would you be able to blacken a little?

Comment: @CHSLD - I can't guess what color/darkness you want. Change `Opacity[.25]` to a larger number[e.g., `.6`) and/or change the color from `LightGray`to `Gray` or any other color the you want.

Comment: Just the normal Gray, not a LightGray. I don't have Mathematica. I just need the image

Comment: @CHSLD "I don't have Mathematica. I just need the image" - well next time, [you can do it yourself](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook).

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[ContourPlot[x^2/6^2 + y^2/4^2 == 1, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 4}, GridLines -> Automatic], 
ContourPlot[x^2/5^2 + y^2/3^2 == 1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 4},  ContourStyle -> Red], 
Table[Graphics[{Opacity[0.15], Rectangle[{x, y}]}], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0,
2}], Graphics[{Opacity[0.15], Rectangle[{4, 0}]}], Graphics[{Opacity[0.15], Rectangle[{4, 1}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you insert the tiles and the bold part as the esquisse?

Comment: Sure thing man!